# iOS - Is hard coding the font / font size bad?

Tags: ios, internationalization

I'm looking to determine how well internationalized an iOS application is, and came across a few instances of code like this:

```
[_lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0]];
```

On other platforms, I would say this is not best practice. For example, if I wanted to decrease the font size for certain languages (due to text expansion), or if I wanted to remove the bolding (e.g. for double byte languages), it would require a code change.

Question - Is this best practice for iOS, and if not what is the alternative?

Disclaimer - I'm not at all familiar with iOS development.

Comment: One of those things that many believe is a personal preference. Some people update their xibs with all the fonts and other do it in code.

Personally I write a "Constants" class that simply has a bunch of class methods giving me the fonts I need.

Comment: I'm thinking from the point of view of localizing it - if the font was stored in the xibs, and it changed, would that also require a recompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS is not as versatile as other platforms for those kind of things, and setting the size and the font in code is a common practice, either in your class or in a external Contanst class, or just set them in Interface Builder if you are using it.

As a personal preference, setting the fonts in Interface Builder makes them harder to see, I prefer to have all the fonts set in my class and see them together. Then, if I change a font, the rest of them will change at the same time, I dont have to go one by one with all the elements in the xib.

In any of the solutions you'll have to recompile every time you change the font.

What I can think in terms of adapting it for different languages could be resizing the label where the text is set doing something like:

```
myLabel.minimumFontSize = 8.;
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

This will shrink the text down to 8 as minimun in case it doesn't fit.

Another practice is to detect the language of your phone and setting the font there, for example:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

And depending on the result do this for language:

```
[_lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:18.0]];
```

and this for example for another:

```
[_lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15.0]];
```